# Associate all Custom Post Types with Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy

I have a custom post type `imagery`. I have a taxonomy `publications`. I need all present and future `imagery` post types have the taxonomy `publications`. Here's a simplified version of code in functions.php:

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomy' => array('publications')
);
register_post_type( 'imagery', $args );
```

..but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You simply made a mistake on the key to use : it's `taxonomies` not `taxonomy`.

```
$args = array(
    'taxonomies' => array('publications')
);
register_post_type( 'imagery', $args );
```